# preg_replace is not working if string has if condition in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using preg_replace for find and replace in string

my string is `$string = if ($('input[name="name[3]"]').is(":checked")) {`

i just want to surround by `""` so I tried like

```
$find = "/(if \(\$\('input\[name=\"name\[3\]\"\]'\).is\(\":checked\"\)\) {)[\s]+/";
$replace = '"$1"';
preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

when I run this query I can see no changes in string i mean no double quotes.

I am doing lot of stuff here but I couldn't able to provide everything, Sorry for that.

Update: In sublimeText3 its working fine like find and replace

Note: I am believing that because of $ sign

Comment: Why not just do `$string = '"' . $string . '"';` to surround it with double quotes?

Comment: I provided only a part of entire string.... so want to find and replace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

Your regex is surrounded by double quotes, which is causing the problem with the escape of the dollar sign `$`.

### Solution 1

You can try this regex:

```
/(if\s\([$]\('input\[name=\"name\[3]\"]'\)\.is\(\":checked\"\)\)\s{)[\s]*/
```

Here's what I've changed:

1. `\$` to `[$]`. It would also work if you change it to `\\$`
2. `reasons-for-visit\[3\]` to `name\[3]` Not sure if this was a typo or something, you can change it back if you need to.
3. `[\s]+` to `[\s]*` since the `+` is one or more. It would not work if it has no space after.

So it would be:

```
$find = "/(if\s\([$]\('input\[name=\"name\[3]\"]'\)\.is\(\":checked\"\)\)\s{)[\s]*/";
$replace = '"$1"';
preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

And the `var_dump` result would be:

```
string(50) ""if ($('input[name="name[3]"]').is(":checked")) {""
```

### Solution 2

You could use single quotes for your regex instead.

---

### Example 1

```
$string = 'Hello $World';
$regex = "/\$/";
var_dump(preg_replace($regex, '!', $string));
```

### Result 1

```
string(13) "Hello $World!"
```

### Example 2

```
$string = 'Hello $World';
$regex = '/\$/'; // Notice the single quote
var_dump(preg_replace($regex, '!', $string));
```

### Result 2

```
string(12) "Hello !World"
```

### Example 3

```
$string = 'Hello $World';
$regex = "/\\$/";
var_dump(preg_replace($regex, '!', $string));
```

### Result 3

```
string(12) "Hello !World"
```